Pino logging to MongoDB
From what I understand, Pino does logging and has ways to transport messages to different directories and to grafana loki API. I am wondering if there is a similar built in way to have the messages go out to a mongo table as well.

I found a repo for this:
https://github.com/pinojs/pino-mongodb
Although getting endless problems trying to implement it.
